# Can I find out the real cause of this error? (React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

First I apologize for my English. I have been working on React to native applications for 4 months. But sometimes I get this error and don't mind.

**Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in %s.%s, the componentWillUnmount method,
in CustomerDetailScreen (at SceneView.tsx:123)**

This is because when I click the button, I open a screen, and when the screen is not fully loaded I press the back button. How can I resolve this warning? I'll show you some sample code examples.

I hope I could explain. Can you help me with this topic? I want to fully understand the logic. I've read something called AbortController in some articles but I don't know exactly.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._isMounted = false;
    this.state = {
        id: props.route.params.id,
        username: '',
        token: null,
        cityId: 1,
        townId: 1,
        cityData: [],
        townData: [],
        selectedIndex: 0,
        selectedCity: new IndexPath(0),
        selectedTown: new IndexPath(0),
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    this._isMounted && this._getToken();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
}

_getToken = async () => {        
    try {
      const username = await AsyncStorage.getItem('username');
      const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');

      if(token === null) {
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem('token');
      }else {
        this.setState({ username: username, token: token });
        this._isMounted && this.loadCustomerDetail();
      }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};

loadCustomerDetail() {
    try {
        const { username, token } = this.state;

        if(token) {
            const { id } = this.state;

            var credentials = Base64.btoa(username + ':' + token);
            var URL         = `https://portal.xxxxxx.com/api/v1/Customer/${id}`;
                
            axios.get(URL, {headers : { 'Espo-Authorization' : credentials }})
            .then(this.dataSuccess.bind(this))
            .catch(this.dataFail.bind(this));                
        }
    }catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};

dataSuccess(response) {
    this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        cityId: response.data.cityId,
        townId: response.data.townId
    }, () => {
        this.getCities();
    });
}

getCities() {
    const { username, token, cityId } = this.state;

    let credentials = Base64.btoa(username + ':' + token);

    axios.get('https://portal.xxxxx.com/api/v1/Cities', { headers : { 'Espo-Authorization' : credentials }})
    .then((response) => {
            response.data.list.sort(function(a, b) {
                return Number(a.id) > Number(b.id);
            });
            
            this.setState({cityData: response.data.list}, () => {
                this.setState({ selectedCity: new IndexPath(this.state.cityData[cityId-1].id - 1) });
                this.getTowns(this.state.cityData[cityId-1].id);
            });
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

getTowns(cityId) {
    this.setState({ townLoading: true });

    const { username, token } = this.state;

    let credentials = Base64.btoa(username + ':' + token);

    axios.get(`https://portal.xxxxx.com/api/v1/Towns/action/TownList?cityId=${cityId}`, { headers : { 'Espo-Authorization' : credentials }})
      .then((response) => {
            this.setState({ townData: response.data, townLoading: false }, () => {
                for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.state.townData)) {
                    if(value.id === this.state.townId) {
                        this.setState({ selectedTown: new IndexPath(key) })
                    }
                }
            });                
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example area:

```
this.setState({ username: username, token: token });
this._isMounted && this.loadCustomerDetail();
```

You can see that `setState` will be called even if the component is no longer mounted.

## Fix

Ensure component is mounted before changing state:

```
if (this._isMounted) {
  this.setState({ username: username, token: token });
  this.loadCustomerDetail();
}
```